# Populate "List Box" with Advanced Filter (Unique Values Only)

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

Excel 2007

I have about 1000 rows in column A of which 250 are unique.  I need the 250 unique rows to show up in a form where the user selects multiple items.  I'be been using macro recorder with the advanced filter and can't get the list to populate.  I'm trying to assign the list to a Range variable.

```
Public Sub UniqueCMFundList()

Dim CMFundList As Range
Dim RangeVar1 As Range
Dim RangeVar2 As Range

Sheets("HiddenDataList").Activate

Range("A2").Select
Set RangeVar1 = Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Set CMFundList = RangeVar1.AdvancedFilter(xlFilterInPlace, , , True)

'This is what I get with macro recorder:
        'Range("A1:A1089").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:= _
            ' Range("A1:A1089"), Unique:=True

Debug.Print CMFundList.Value


End Sub
```

Comment: Do you get an error message? If so, what is it and what line does it refer to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Dim arrUnqItems As Variant

    With Sheets("HiddenDataList")
        .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, , .Cells(1, .Columns.Count), True
        arrUnqItems = Application.Transpose(.Range(.Cells(2, .Columns.Count), .Cells(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).End(xlUp)).Value)
        .Columns(.Columns.Count).Clear
    End With

    Me.ListBox1.Clear
    Me.ListBox1.List = arrUnqItems

    Erase arrUnqItems

End Sub
```

Comment: heh, I never noticed before that Tranpose changes a column array to a vector. Useful :-)

Comment: Thank you. I'm a VB novice.  I'm not getting any errors but nothing is showing up in the ListBox either?      My UserForm (Name) is "ErshProofingFile" and my ListBox (Name) is "ListBox_SelectCMFund" so I replaced "UserForm_Initialize()" with "ListBox_SelectCMFund" and "ListBox1" with "ListBox_SelectCMFund".

Comment: If you changed the sub name, you'll need to run the sub manually.  I would recommend leaving the sub name as "UserForm_Initialize".  That is a keyword sub name that will run when the userform is first loaded.  So basically, it will populate the listbox on open.

Comment: Struggling to understand exactly what is happening here:
.Range("A1... : copying unique values
arrUnqItems = : transposing values from columnar to array
.Columns... .Clear: clearing columns
How is the result of xlFilterCopy being passed to Application.Transpose? Why are columns being cleared? I commented out that line in my sample workbook but nothing was visible.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this using a Collection object. For large worksheets it should be a lot faster than filtering, particularly if there are formulae involved. Note that if you want a collection returned then just change the last bit that converts the collection to an array (the array is for your convenience for the list box)

I use a slightly more nuanced variant of the below adapted for array and range arguments and switches to ignore stuff all the time and it is pretty darn quick.

```
'Just use it like:
Me.ListBox1.List = GetUniqueItems(Range("A1:A100"))

Public Function GetUniqueItems(rng As Range) As Variant()

    Dim c As Collection
    Dim arr, ele
    Dim i As Long
    Dim area As Range

    Set c = New Collection

    For Each area In rng.Areas

        arr = area.Value
        On Error Resume Next
        If IsArray(arr) Then
            For Each ele In arr
                c.Add ele, VarType(ele) & "|" & CStr(ele)
            Next ele
        Else
            c.Add arr, VarType(arr) & "|" & CStr(arr)
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0

    Next area

    If c.Count > 0 Then
        ReDim arr(0 To c.Count - 1)
        For i = 0 To UBound(arr)
            arr(i) = c(i + 1)
        Next i
        GetUniqueItems = arr
    End If

End Function
```

Alternatively, an advanced filter (in place - there is no need for the overhead of copying the data elsewhere):

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim uniques
Set rng = Range("A1:A1001")
rng.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, Unique:=True
uniques = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Intersect(rng, rng.Offset(1, 0)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value)
rng.Show 'not necessary if you are only using the worksheet as hidden etc but this removes the filter
Me.Listbox1.List = uniques
```

Comment: I'm a VB novice.  Thank you for your help.  I still can't get anything to show up in my [ListBox (Name) ListBox_SelectCMFund] which is part of [UserForm (Name) ErshProofingFile].  I tried the code and tried updating the RowSource property but it's just blank.